# General SDL2 problems. MacOS, Xode

Tags: c++, macos, sdl-2

What I'm trying to do is make an SDL program that can write special symbols to a window I created. The keyboard can change between 4 layers each registering 32 keys. I just can't figure out how to actually make something appear on the screen and have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    //Setup
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event event;
    int z = 0;  //Layer
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    //Init
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    SDL_Window * window = SDL_CreateWindow("TPKB", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 960, 640, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Rect rect = {x, y, 32, 32};
    SDL_Renderer * renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    SDL_Surface * A_srf = SDL_LoadBMP("A.bmp"); SDL_Texture * A = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, A_srf); SDL_FreeSurface(A_srf);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);


    //Events
    while (!quit)
    {
        SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
        switch (event.type)
        {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYUP:
            {
                if(z == 0)
                {
                    switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                    {
                        //case SDLK_1: SDL_BlitSurface(A_srf, NULL, surface, srfrect); break;
                        case SDLK_2: SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, A, NULL, &rect); if(x == 928){x = 0; y += 32;} else{x += 32;} rect.x = x; rect.y = y; SDL_RenderClear(renderer); SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); break;
                        case SDLK_LEFT: z = 1; std::cout << "1"; break;
                    }
                }
                if(z == 1)
                {
                    switch(event.key.keysym.sym)
                    {
                        case SDLK_UP: z = 0; std::cout << "0"; break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Cleanup
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(A);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried moving the render clear render present stuff around but it hasn't seemed to be activating at all.

Comment: If your problem is with displaying anything, perhaps it is a good idea to only display single thing without any keyboard and other unrelated stuff. `RenderClear` fills image with solid colour, and then you present that result, whatever `RenderCopy` you did before that is overwritten. Usually clear performed at the start of the frame and renderpresent finishes it.

Comment: @keltar thanks, I did what you said and it finally somewhat works, however when I press the button again it does half of what I expected, how can I make it show multiple of the picture at the same time.

Comment: You'll have to do that in a very different way (of course there is more than one way to do so). First, separate your event processing and rendering. Generally event processing should never draw anything but modify some data that you can use later to render required things. Then use e.g. array of elements you want to draw and append new element in event processing. Rendering code should just iterate over array and render everything.